# How i can use Mailchimp API directtly without using Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3. I want to subscribe user to

mailchimp. But when i use gems like(gibbon and mailchimp_api).There are

too many dependencies issues. Mailchimp developer guide not help me too

much.I spent many days but not solve these issues.

How can i make direct api calls to mailchimp for subscribe users?

Any help?

Comment: Can you describe the dependency issues you're hitting?

Comment: can you elaborate - 'There are too many dependencies issues.'

Comment: Yes when i install gibbon then i need to move my ruby version from 1.9.3 to 2.1.3. Then this error occur try_sass': uninitialized constant Haml::Util::Sass (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Resolving your dependency issues with Gibbon should be a cinch: it only relies on two things:

1. `gem 'faraday', '>= 0.9.1'`
2. `gem 'multi_json', '>= 1.11.0'`

If you're unable to use a recent version of each of those, you probably have something else awry.

---

As for working with Mailchimp directly, their [developer guides](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) do a great job of walking you through how to obtain API tokens for other users using OAuth2 and explaining the endpoints that are available. You then just need to make HTTP requests (e.g. with Faraday v0.9.1 or greater), parse the responses (e.g. with multi_json 1.11.0 or greater) and write logic to handle errors.

If you want to get started faster, you could look at the source for Gibbon. You can even get away with copy-pasting the entirety of Gibbon into a gem of your own naming and modify the code to not rely on those dependencies.

Comment: But after my local dev i need to deploy on heroku. so copy pasting not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> ...when i install gibbon then i need to move my ruby version from 1.9.3 to 2.1.3

You can use an earlier version of Gibbon that supports Ruby 1.9.3. It looks like the last version to support Ruby 1.9.3 is [Gibbon 1.2.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/gibbon/versions/1.2.1).